# "Cannot return value referencing temporary value" in function returning tuple

Tags: rust

```
fn gen_order()-> (&'static String, &'static String, &'static String){
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

    let prices = [0.00,72.99, 72.99, 899.99, 499.99, 9.99, 9.99, 0.99, 899.99, 72.99, 1234.99];
    let product_ids = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
    let products_id = rng.gen_range(1..10);
    let cust_id = rng.gen_range(1..24);
    let order_total = prices[products_id];

    return (&product_ids[products_id].to_string(), &String::from(cust_id.to_string()), &String::from(order_total.to_string()));
}
```

I have the basic function up above the generates the tuple and returns it. I'm getting "cannot return value referencing temporary value". How would I go about fixing this issue? I know it's a lifetime issue.

I tried adding the `static` keyword to the return value in the function header but for some reason it did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do *any* borrowing here. `to_string` returns a newly allocated `String` by value, so simply return the same by *value*.

```
fn gen_order() -> (String, String, String) {
  ...
  return (
    product_ids[products_id].to_string(),
    cust_id.to_string(),
    order_total.to_string(),
  );
}
```